# iOS giving incompatible pointer types assignment error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using below code, it gives the error:

```
incompatible pointer types assignment to 'NSString *'
to the parament of the 'NSString *'" where  dataParameter is used.
```

Here is the code:

```
 - (id)initWithText:(NSString *)someText passedData:(animalsViewController *)dataParameter  
{

  NSLog(dataParameter);
  self.title=dataParameter;
  nowCountry=dataParameter;

  return self;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should stick to the common Objective-C conventions and start the names of you classes with uppercase letters (`AnimalsViewController`).

Comment: thanks :) i am very new to this language.. i will take care of naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating "dataParameter", which is an instance of "animalsViewController" as an NSString. That doesn't work, you can only assign objects of the same type to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` is expecting a string parameter.  Use the formatting arguments to convert `dataParameter` to an `NSString`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dataParameter);
```

For your other two assignments, it seems unlikely that you want to assign a viewController object to a property like title that is an `NSString`.  It's more likely that you want to assign an `NSString` property of `dataParameter`, something like this:

```
self.title = dataParameter.title;
```

or:

```
nowCountry = dataParameter.country;
```

Since I don't know what properties an `AnimalsViewController` has, I'm just guessing a property names, but that should illustrate the point.

Comment: thanks it solved the NSLog error, but how can i solve for   self.title=dataParameter; and nowCountry=dataParameter;